# Сгруппированное количество пользователей которые впервые появились в таблице за конкретный период

Tags: sql, postgresql

Есть таблица в которую каждый день сохраняется количество покупок пользователя (сколько за этот день он купил):
user_id, count_buy, create_time (Это всегда timestamp конкретного дня).
Необходимо было узнать количество пользователей, которые сделали первую покупку в конкретный промежуток времени (В данном случае я вычисляю сначала количество людей у которых это сделка не первая):

```
select count(distinct user_id) from stat where
user_id in(select user_id from stat where create_time >= '2019-03-01' and    
create_time <= '2019-03-31' group by user_id) and create_time < '2019-03-01';
```

Этот запрос выводит количество пользователей у которых в марте покупка была НЕ первой ( потом я просто вычитаю из общего количества пользователей, которые покупали это значение и получаю нужный результат).

Но появляется задача выводить группированные списки за 12 месяцев. То есть ту же самую информацию только за 12 месяцев, и по каждому из месяцев количество первых покупок. Я оказался в тупике. Потому что мой подход уже не работает. Выход только делать несколько запросов и через цикл в PHP, но хотелось бы делать это на SQL, чтобы не менять стиль проекта.

Если знаете более нормальные способы для решения задачи или можете помочь с группировкой для такого запроса - буду благодарен.

Comment: А что есть "первая покупка" ? Это за всю жизнь пользователя, или первая в конкретном месяце и в следующем будет своя первая ?

Comment: За всю жизнь пользователя. То есть в этом месяце он совершил покупку и если ранее никогда в жизне он её не совершал - то она считается первой.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select date_trunc('month', date), count(1)
  from (
    select user_id, min(create_time) date
      from stat
     group by user_id
  ) x
 group by date_trunc('month', date)
```

Внутренний подзапрос получает по каждому пользователю дату его первой покупки. Внешний собирает даты в месяцы и считает пользователей. Ограничения по датам на год добавить по вкусу, во внешнем запросе

Comment: Гениально, спасибо! Даже не подумал о таком подходе.